# Scrapy, python, Xpath how to match respective items in html

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new to Xpath, trying to scrapy website with below format:

```
<div class="top">
    <a> tittle_name </a>
    <div class="middle"> listed_date </div>
    <div class="middle"> listed_value </div>
</div>
<div class="top">
    <a> tittle_name </a>
    <div class="middle"> listed_date </div>
</div>
<div class="top">
    <a> tittle_name </a>
    <div class="middle"> listed_value </div>
</div>
```

The presences of listed_value & listed_date are optional.

I need to group each tittle_name with respective listed_date, listed_value (if available) then insert reach record to MySQL.

I am using [**scrapy shell**](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/shell.html) which gives some basic examples like

```
listings = hxs.select('//div[@class=\'top\']')
for listing in listings:
    tittle_name = listing.select('/a//text()').extract()
    date_values = listing.select('//div[@class=\'middle\']')
```

Above code give me list of tittle_name and list of available listed_date, listed_value, **but how to match them**? (we cannot go by index because the format is not symmetric).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do note that those XPath expressions are absolute:

```
/a//text()

//div[@class=\'middle\']
```

You would need relative XPath expression like these:

```
a

div[@class=\'middle\']
```

Second. It's not a good idea to select text nodes in a mixed content model like (X)HTML. You should extract the string value with the proper DOM method or with `string()` function. (In the last case, you would need to eval the expression **for each node** because the implicit node set casting into singleton node set)

Comment: I think no issue with relative or absolute paths here since I call "//div[@class=\'middle\']" from listing which is the result of listings = hxs.select('//div[@class=\'top\']'). Thanks for the note in text & string(), I will look into it when refining the code later on. I do NOT really understand your last sentence. Is this a suggestion to match related entries for each node. If yes, could you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the website doesn't specify whether something in a `div[@class='middle']` is a date or a value, you'll have to code your own way of deciding this.

I guess the dates have some specific format that you could match with some analysis, maybe using a regular expression.

Can you maybe be more specific on what are possible values for `listed_date` and `listed_value`?

Comment: yeah, you are right. able to decide on listed_date & listed_value. BUT each tittle_name might have either listed_date or listed_value, might have both, or might have none. THE FORMAT IS NOT SYMMETRIC. So, from the list I got in Python code above, I do NOT know how to match tittle_name with respective listed_date, listed_value when trying to insert in MySQL. Maybe a different approach required?